# Why mostly values are multiples of 8 in Android xml?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, margin

Why most of the time if we have to create a margin, padding or anything inside xml we use multiples of 8 or 4?

I was trying to know what is the possible reason for this? Why isn't it an odd number mostly ?

Comment: That's because of the baseline grid. Refer this https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#baseline-grid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spacing methods and layout grids define structure, hierarchy, and rhythm in your design. When correctly used, they **reduce decision-making and help establish a rational approach to type scales, positioning, sizing, and spacing.**

**Base Unit**

- The base unit defines what every measurement will be a multiple of.
- This keeps designs consistent, improves communication with developers, and reduces the number of decisions a designer has to make.
- The most recommended base unit is **8px** because it makes scaling for a wide variety of devices easy and consistent.
- **This is because most screen sizes are divisible by 8 and because 8 is itself an easily divisible number (8/2=4, 8/4=2).**

[image: Base Unit]

On other hand, as [Material Design](https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#baseline-grid) (is a design system – backed by open-source code – that helps teams build high-quality digital experiences.) explained,

- All components align to an 8dp square baseline grid for mobile, tablet, and desktop.
- Icons, type, and some elements within components can align to a 4dp grid.

Refer to these articles for more details,

1. [Everything you need to know as a UI designer about spacing & layout grids](https://medium.com/design-with-figma/everything-you-need-to-know-as-a-ui-designer-about-spacing-layout-grids-2bc269e12321)
2. [8pt Material Design GUI Templates](https://medium.com/@_bklmn/8pt-gui-templates-ed8798badab3)